# Almost everywhere equal functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let X be a measure space $\\$
$A \subset X$
And $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb R$
s.t $$ f(x)=\cases{1& if $x\in A $\\
0 & if $x \notin A$}$$
Then does f=0 almost everywhere?And why yes why not?

Comment: Should that say $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ instead?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom is it ok now?

Comment: Are we given any information about $X$ (e.g. is $X$ a measure space)?  Any information about $A$ (e.g. do we know the measure of $A$)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes it is a measure space and we don't know the measure of A .

Comment: if and only if $A$ has measure zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu \{x:f(x)\neq 0\}=A$, so $f=0$ a.e iff $\mu (A)=0$.

Comment: Then your saying that the Dirac measure is zero a.e? if we have dirac of an element , cz the measure of sigleton is always zero . isn't it?

Comment: @sarafkh If $\mu =\delta_y$ then $f=0$ a.e iff $y \notin A$.

Comment: I cant understand can u explain more plz??

Comment: @sarafkh $\delta_y(A)=1$ if $y \in A$ and $0$ if $y \notin A$. Hence $\delta_y(A)=0$  is equivalent to $y \notin A$.

Comment: Do you know the answer of this unrelated ques: why is the integral of a continuous function on a compact set finite ? Do you know?

Comment: @sarafkh Hint: Use that a continuous function is bounded on a compact set.

Comment: @Pazu Ok but who says that the measure of compact is finite though?

Comment: @sarafkh If you consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ then compact is equivalent to bounded and closed.

Comment: @Pazu perhaps we  don't consider $\mathbb R^{n}$ then what would be else? Radon measure you mean?